# VBA Convert and combine date and time

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and am working an a macro that will help me transform call records into something useful for analysis.

Column E contains the Date of Call which is formatted YYYYMMDD. I need to convert to MM/DD/YYYY. (i.e. 20140101 convert to 1/1/2014)

Column F contains the Time of Call which is formatted HHMMSS or HMMSS depending on whether the hour has two digits or one. I need to convert to HH:MM:SS (i.e. 130101 or 90101 which needs to convert to 13:01:01 and 9:01:01, respectively). Because the hour is missing the tens digit if the value is below ten, (below) I have added a "0" to the beginning of the value so I can use the date function.

I currently enter the the following formula in Column K and autofill until the end of the range:

> =DATE(LEFT(E2,4),MID(E2,5,2),RIGHT(E2,2))+TIME(LEFT(IF(LEN(F2)=5, 0&F2, F2),2),MID(IF(LEN(F2)=5, 0&F2, F2),3,2),RIGHT(IF(LEN(F2)=5, 0&F2, F2),2))

The formula results in a value like "1/1/2013 13:01:01".

Can someone help me write the VBA code to automate this process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Created separate UDFs for this. Paste the following into a module.

```
Function MorphDate(DateRng As Range)

    Dim DateStr As String: DateStr = DateRng.Value
    Dim Yr As String, Mt As String, Dy As String

    Yr = Left(DateStr, 4)
    Mt = Mid(DateStr, 5, 2)
    Dy = Right(DateStr, 2)

    MorphDate = Format(DateSerial(Yr, Mt, Dy), "m/dd/yyyy")

End Function

Function MorphTime(TimeRng As Range)

    Dim TimeStr As String: TimeStr = TimeRng.Value
    Dim Hh As String, Mm As String, Ss As String

    If Len(TimeStr) = 5 Then TimeStr = "0" & TimeStr

    Hh = Left(TimeStr, 2)
    Mm = Mid(TimeStr, 3, 2)
    Ss = Right(TimeStr, 2)

    MorphTime = Format(TimeSerial(Hh, Mm, Ss), "hh:mm:ss")
End Function

Function MorphDateTime(DateRng As Range, TimeRng As Range)

    Application.Volatile
    MorphDateTime = CDate(MorphDate(DateRng)) + CDate(MorphTime(TimeRng))

End Function
```

Now you can use the formulas `MorphDate` to change the date, `MorphTime` to change the time, and `MorphDateTime` for a combination of both.

Screenshot:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

**EDIT:**

If you want to use it inside a subroutine, add the following code to the module:

```
Sub MorphingTime()

    Dim DateRng As Range, Cell As Range
    Set DateRng = Range("E2:E100") '--Modify as needed.

    For Each Cell in DateRng
        Range("K" & Cell.Row).Value = MorphDateTime(Cell, Cell.Offset(0,1))
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great. As a follow up, if I wanted to incorporate this into a Sub routine, how would I do it? The range for Date is E2 until the end and Time is F2 until the end.